# Excel VBA - Add one to each referenced cell when running macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have tried searching for the answer for the past couple hours but cannot seem to find what I am looking for - mind you, I am really new to VBA and macros.

What I am trying to do is to add one to what my formula is referencing to every time the macro is run. For example:

Currently the formula is `=100*((Q$179/Q$167)-1)`

When run, I would like it to be `=100*((Q$180/Q$168)-1)`

I have to do this for multiple formulas. Is there an easy way to do this with a macro?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Is your formula used in the worksheet or in your code?

Comment: It is used in the worksheet

Comment: Why do yo need a macro for this? You can just copy that formula down and Excel adjusts the formula automatically. Please provide more background information. What are you actually trying to do? What is the goal behind your question?

Comment: The simply solution is to modify the formula to use a helper cell to determine the range, `=100*((Q$180/INDIRECT("Q$"&A1,TRUE))-1)`

Comment: So the formulas will remain in the same cells.

Essentially what I am doing is that I have a worksheet that I need to update at the end of every month. I insert a new row above for every month and then these formulas need to be updated by one to link to the new row of data that I make.

Comment: Imagine this, I have rows of data above (one row for every month). At the end of the month, I insert a new row below last month's data. I have a section below with formulas that calculate data based on the new month's data. Obviously, with the new row, I must now link these formulas to the new month as they are previously linked to last month's data. They are all different formulas calculating different things which is why it makes it complicated otherwise I would just update one and then paste special the rest.

Comment: If the number you need to update is the last row of column Q I’ll use indirect to retrieve last row value: =INDIRECT("Q$"&(MIN(ROW(Q:Q))+ROW(Q:Q)-1))

Comment: This doesn't really help answer your particuar question but if you're having to do this in the first place I think your worksheet setup could be optimised a little!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use RegEx to achieve this. The following will increment every cells row by 1 in your formula. This should also work on columns other then `Q` as well

```
Option Explicit
Sub IncrementFormula()
    Dim tmpFormula As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim Match, SubMatch

    tmpFormula = "=100*((Q$179/Q$167)-1)"

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(?:[A-Z]{1,})(?:\$|)([0-9]{1,})"

        If .test(tmpFormula) Then
            For Each Match In .Execute(tmpFormula)
                For Each SubMatch In Match.submatches
                    tmpFormula = Replace(tmpFormula, Match, Replace(Match, SubMatch, vbNullString) & CLng(SubMatch) + 1)
                Next SubMatch
            Next Match
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox tmpFormula
End Sub
```

Using your formula above it will output `=100*((Q$180/Q$168)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to persist when the workbook is closed, you'll need to store your number somewhere in a worksheet. Say it's in Cell(1,1) of Sheets(2), you could use

```
    dim incVal as integer
    incVal = cint(Sheets(2).Cells(1,1))+1
    Sheets(2).Cells(1,1) = incVal
    dim formula as string
    formula = "=100*((Q$" & incVal & "/Q$" & (incVal-12) & ")-1)"
```

Then just set the desired Cell's formula to that formula. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to use `OFFSET` in your formula

Assuming the formula is in `Q185`

then:

```
=100*((Q$180/Q$168)-1)
```

Becomes:

```
 =100*((OFFSET(Q185,-5,0)/OFFSET(Q185,-17,0)-1))
```

As you insert rows at the bottom of the table (and above the formulas), the formula and the cell it refers to will also move down

Comment: Thank you very much for this, this solved my problem - did not even need to use VBA.